# Multiple different kinds of plots on a single figure and save it to a video

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot multiple different plots on a single matplotlib figure with in a for loop. At the moment it is all good in matlab as shown in the picture below and then am able to save the figure as a video frame. [Here](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtEnXvOorHZ4sqB0zC2PrNpaJFdQ0w?e=xdl4ge) is a link of a sample video generated in matlab for 10 frames

[image]

In python, tried it as below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for frame in range(FrameStart,FrameEnd):#loop1
# data generation code within a for loop for n frames from source video
array1 = np.zeros((200, 3800))
array2 = np.zeros((19,2))
array3 = np.zeros((60,60))
for i in range(len(array2)):#loop2
#generate data for arrays 1 to 3 from the frame data
#end loop2
plt.subplot(6,1,1)
plt.imshow(DataArray,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(6, 1, 2)
plt.bar(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.contourf(mapData)
# for fourth plot, use array2[3] and array2[5], plot it as shown and keep the\is #plot without erasing for next frame
```

[image]

not sure how to do the 4th axes with line plots. This needs to be there (done using hold on for this axis in matlab) for the entire sequence of frames processing in the for loop while the other 3 axes needs to be erased and updated with new data for each frame in the movie. The contour plot needs to be square all the time with color bar on the side. At the end of each frame processing, once all the axes are updated, it needs to be saved as a frame of a movie. Again this is easily done in matlab, but not sure in python.

Any suggestions

thanks

Comment: Please show your data which you are using @user1524182

Comment: The data is huge which is the reason why I havent included the actual data, but you can use any random data where the sizes would be as shown in attached updated pictures in the original post along with updated code flow, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this format.

I have used `comments #` in code to answer your queries. Please check the snippet
[image: subplots]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(311) #3rows 1 column 1st plot
ax2=fig.add_subplot(312) #3rows 1 column 2nd plot
ax3=fig.add_subplot(325) #3rows 2 column 5th plot
ax4=fig.add_subplot(326) #3rows 2 column 6th plot
plt.show()
```

[image: Plots]

To turn off `ticks` you can use `plt.axis('off')`. I dont know how to interpolate your format so left it blank . You can adjust your `figsize` based on your requirements.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))  #First is width Second is height

ax1=fig.add_subplot(311)        
ax2=fig.add_subplot(312)      
ax3=fig.add_subplot(325)        
ax4=fig.add_subplot(326)        

#Bar Plot
langs = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'PHP']
students = [23,17,35,29,12]
ax2.bar(langs,students)

#Contour Plot
xlist = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100)
ylist = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
Z = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
cp = ax3.contourf(X, Y, Z)
fig.colorbar(cp,ax=ax3)                #Add a colorbar to a plot

#Multiple line plot
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
y1 = 2*x + 1
y2 = 2**x + 1
ax4.plot(x, y2)
ax4.plot(x, y1, color='red',linewidth=1.0)

plt.tight_layout()              #Make sures plots dont overlap
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks looks good, but the fourth plot needs to be one thats updated for each frame in the for loop with one data point per frame. So, by the end of loop1 you will have a dual line plot. In matlab this is done by calling as below key being the use of hold on so that it wont erase in the for loop while others do --   `ax(4) = subplot(5,2,[8 10]);`
    `plot(frame,y1,'.b',y2,'.r'); `
    `ylim([-4 2]);xlim([FrameStart FrameEnd]);`
    `hold on`

Comment: It is also not updating after it shows the figure and plots for the first time in the for loop. See the sample video that is generated by matlab in my original post to get an idea.

Comment: @user1524182 So you just need your dual line plot using for loop? that is the only thing right? you want live plot also? moving x and y axis?

Comment: All four plots are needed in the for loop. For example, if you look at the link in the original post, you can see all plots being updated in real-time with the difference that the dual line plot is only updated with two data values once per loop iteration and retains its plot for the next iteration while the other three plots are cleared and updated. In that example, the for loop runs for 200 frames hence plot4 goes from 1 to 200

Comment: @user1524182 I appologize that I wont be able to help you further regarding realtime `countour and imshow` plots. But regarding `line` plot, I would suggest you to take a look at this **https://youtu.be/ZmYPzESC5YY** and **https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/** for animations using `matplotlib`. ..`Histogram` is also there in 2nd link, please check it.. I only know to achieve all your results using `google charts and chartJS` i.e. **to display in website realtime** .But with `matplotlib`  I wont be able to help you further. **All the best**

Comment: No worries, it looks like it working the way I like except for some axis autoscaling which can be taken care of. The only problem that needs to be addressed now is memory leak and slowing down. As the for loop continues updating plots, memory consumption increases and the whole application slows down. Looking into 'blit' techniques... meanwhle if you have anysuggestions, please let me know

Comment: @user1524182 You need to close the plot also `plt.close()` after using it

Comment: I am not sure if calling plt.close() is the solution as it will close and reopen figure for each for loop iteration.